# Django admin- static files not served- Digital Ocean

Tags: nginx, django-admin, gunicorn, digital-ocean, static-files

Path issue.
How to resolve

> Nginx log
>   2017/12/03 17:06:10 [error] 3001#3001: *53342 open() "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin//css/base.css"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), server: _, request: "GET
>   /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1",

How to remove this extra slash?

EDIT:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin//css/base.css

there is no django in dist-packages
why and how?
pls help

Comment: Can plz you post your nginx configuration?

Comment: I was able to solve this. Yes there was this wrong path entered in nginx configuration. Thanks anyway!